# Magento 2 addAttributeToFilter not working

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter, product-collection

In product collection addAttributeToFilter is not working if we assing attribute value in only store view. But if we assing in default and store view than it working fine.

anyone have idea why it is happening ?

This is my code :

```
$products = $category->getProductCollection();
$products->addFieldToSelect('*');
$products->setStore($storeId);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
$products->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
```

Comment: Please post the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to doing a category product collection.  Can you not use something like this?

```php
public function __construct(   
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
        array $data = []
){    
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

    public function getProductCollection($storeId, $categories = [])
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addStoreFilter($storeid);  
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
        $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());      
        return $collection;
    }
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php#L923-L942

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter a collection on store-specific values (which seems to be the matter in your case), you should either use `setStoreId()` to make the collection aware of which store this collection applies to:

```
$productCollection
    ->setStoreId(int|string|\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $storeId);
```

You can also filter a collection on a store, which also includes the availability for the given store (like visibility):

```
$productCollection
    ->addStoreFilter(int|string|\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $storeId);
```

Although in your case, I suspect a `setStoreId()` would do the trick.

Comment: I have already do same way, Please check my question.

Comment: Just inject store manager dependency and in your function add this code  $collection->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore());